# `scroll` eventListener gives big intervals between `window.scrollY`

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, scroll, delay

I'm handling `scroll` eventListener to get scroll top point and then do some action.

Code looks pretty simple:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  console.log(window.scrollY)
})
```

Although, when I scroll fast, the console gives a really big intervals between points

```
1
60
220
498
787
1157
1844
2161
2458
2741
4158
4277
```

And that causes little delay of my action.

For example if I need to do like this:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  if (window.scrollY > elem.getBoundingClientRect().top) {
    elem.style.position = 'fixed';
    elem.style.top = 0;
  }
})
```

It pins the element after a small delay.

I'm not sure, maybe this is heavy operation for the browser, but anyone knows better way?

Answers in jQuery is also welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: debouncing or throttling would solve this.

Comment: @KevinB As far as I understood the question, Op is not concerned about those events triggering multiple times, but the visual delay which occurs due to the event "only firing once in a while".

Comment: @OP This is really not production ready, but CSS now defines `position:sticky` - atm unfortunately with horrible browser support. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position http://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/

Comment: i was under the impression that the visual delay is happening because the event is happening too often due to lots of scrolling.

Comment: The distance between the points when the events happen shouldn't have any impact on how quickly the change happens, the only thing important is how quickly the events themselves trigger and how quickly the browser render task can run.

Comment: @KevinB when I scroll down slowly, it works nicely. But when I do it fast, it jumps up after it realizes it's outside.

Comment: So, the issue is literally the delta between the events is too large then? in other words, it jumps from, say, 787 to 1157, when it would have swapped to fixed at 790, and that causes a jump of roughly 140px? that's interesting. Not sure if it would even be possible to remedy that.

Comment: I'll try to make a fiddle

Comment: @KevinB Please see my own answer to see what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, guys for the support. It helped a lot.

The solution was using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `scroll eventlistener`. Explaining video here by Paul Irish: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vp524yo0p44

Answer (score 4):

I have come across such issues. Well, in this case, you need to give the static parent a class and using the class, you need to target the fixed element by setting it to `position: fixed`, and calculate the `offsetTop`.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    elem = document.querySelector("#parent");
    if (window.scrollY > elem.offsetTop) {
      elem.classList.add('fixed');
    }
    else {
      elem.classList.remove('fixed');
    }
  });
};
```

```css
h1 {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.fixed h1 {position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; background: #fff;}
```

```html
<p><b>Microsoft Corporation</b> <span class="nowrap"><span class="IPA nopopups"><a href="/wiki/Help:IPA_for_English" title="Help:IPA for English">/<span style="border-bottom:1px dotted"><span title="/ˈ/ primary stress follows">ˈ</span><span title="'m' in 'my'">m</span><span title="/aɪ/ long 'i' in 'tide'">aɪ</span><span title="'k' in 'kind'">k</span><span title="'r' in 'rye'">r</span><span title="/ɵ/ variable 1st 'o' in 'omission'">ɵ</span><span title="'s' in 'sigh'">s</span><span title="/ɒː/ variable 'o' as in 'coffee'">ɒː</span><span title="'f' in 'find'">f</span><span title="'t' in 'tie'">t</span></span>/</a></span></span> (commonly referred to as <b>Microsoft</b>) is an American <a href="/wiki/Multinational_corporation" title="Multinational corporation">multinational</a> <a href="/wiki/Technology_company" title="Technology company">technology company</a> headquartered in <a href="/wiki/Redmond,_Washington" title="Redmond, Washington">Redmond</a>, <a href="/wiki/Washington_(state)" title="Washington (state)">Washington</a>, that develops, manufactures, licenses, supports and sells <a href="/wiki/Computer_software" title="Computer software" class="mw-redirect">computer software</a>, <a href="/wiki/Consumer_electronics" title="Consumer electronics">consumer electronics</a> and <a href="/wiki/Personal_computers" title="Personal computers" class="mw-redirect">personal computers</a> and services. Its best known software products are the <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Windows" title="Microsoft Windows">Microsoft Windows</a> line of <a href="/wiki/Operating_systems" title="Operating systems" class="mw-redirect">operating systems</a>, <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Office" title="Microsoft Office">Microsoft Office</a> <a href="/wiki/Office_suite" title="Office suite" class="mw-redirect">office suite</a>, and <a href="/wiki/Internet_Explorer" title="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</a> and <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Edge" title="Microsoft Edge">Edge</a> <a href="/wiki/Web_browser" title="Web browser">web browsers</a>. Its flagship hardware products are the <a href="/wiki/Xbox" title="Xbox">Xbox</a> game consoles and the <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Surface" title="Microsoft Surface">Microsoft Surface</a> tablet lineup. It is the <a href="/wiki/List_of_the_largest_software_companies" title="List of the largest software companies">world's largest software maker</a> measured by revenues. It is also one of the <a href="/wiki/List_of_corporations_by_market_capitalization" title="List of corporations by market capitalization" class="mw-redirect">world's most valuable companies</a>.</p>
<div id="parent">
  <h1>I will be fixed later!</h1>
</div>
<p>Microsoft was founded by <a href="/wiki/Paul_Allen" title="Paul Allen">Paul Allen</a> and <a href="/wiki/Bill_Gates" title="Bill Gates">Bill Gates</a> on April 4, 1975, to develop and sell <a href="/wiki/BASIC" title="BASIC">BASIC</a> <a href="/wiki/Interpreter_(computer_software)" title="Interpreter (computer software)" class="mw-redirect">interpreters</a> for <a href="/wiki/Altair_8800" title="Altair 8800">Altair 8800</a>. It rose to dominate the <a href="/wiki/Personal_computer" title="Personal computer">personal computer</a> <a href="/wiki/Operating_system" title="Operating system">operating system</a> market with <a href="/wiki/MS-DOS" title="MS-DOS">MS-DOS</a> in the mid-1980s, followed by <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Windows" title="Microsoft Windows">Microsoft Windows</a>. The company's 1986 <a href="/wiki/Initial_public_offering" title="Initial public offering">initial public offering</a>, and subsequent rise in its share price, created three billionaires and an estimated 12,000 millionaires from Microsoft employees. Since the 1990s, it has increasingly diversified from the operating system market and has <a href="/wiki/List_of_mergers_and_acquisitions_by_Microsoft" title="List of mergers and acquisitions by Microsoft">made a number of corporate acquisitions</a>. In May 2011, Microsoft acquired <a href="/wiki/Skype_Technologies" title="Skype Technologies">Skype Technologies</a> for $8.5 billion in its largest acquisition to date.</p>
<p>As of 2015, Microsoft is market dominant in both the <a href="/wiki/IBM_PC-compatible" title="IBM PC-compatible" class="mw-redirect">IBM PC-compatible</a> operating system (while it lost the majority of the overall operating system market to <a href="/wiki/Android_(operating_system)" title="Android (operating system)">Android</a>) and <a href="/wiki/Office_software_suite" title="Office software suite" class="mw-redirect">office software suite</a> markets (the latter with <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Office" title="Microsoft Office">Microsoft Office</a>). The company also produces a wide range of other software for desktops and servers, and is active in areas including <a href="/wiki/Web_search_engine" title="Web search engine">Internet search</a> (with <a href="/wiki/Bing" title="Bing">Bing</a>), the <a href="/wiki/Video_game_industry" title="Video game industry">video game industry</a> (with the <a href="/wiki/Xbox_(console)" title="Xbox (console)">Xbox</a>, <a href="/wiki/Xbox_360" title="Xbox 360">Xbox 360</a> and <a href="/wiki/Xbox_One" title="Xbox One">Xbox One</a> consoles), the digital services market (through <a href="/wiki/MSN" title="MSN">MSN</a>), and mobile phones (via the operating systems of Nokia's former phones and <a href="/wiki/Windows_Phone" title="Windows Phone">Windows Phone</a> OS). In June 2012, Microsoft entered the personal computer production market for the first time, with the launch of the <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Surface" title="Microsoft Surface">Microsoft Surface</a>, a line of <a href="/wiki/Tablet_computer" title="Tablet computer">tablet computers</a>.</p>
<p>With the acquisition of Nokia's devices and services division to form <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Mobile" title="Microsoft Mobile">Microsoft Mobile Oy</a>, the company re-entered the smartphone hardware market, after its previous attempt, <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Kin" title="Microsoft Kin">Microsoft Kin</a>, which resulted from their acquisition of <a href="/wiki/Danger_(company)" title="Danger (company)">Danger Inc.</a></p>
<p>Microsoft is a portmanteau of the words <b>micro</b>computer and <b>soft</b>ware.</p>
<p><b>Microsoft Corporation</b> <span class="nowrap"><span class="IPA nopopups"><a href="/wiki/Help:IPA_for_English" title="Help:IPA for English">/<span style="border-bottom:1px dotted"><span title="/ˈ/ primary stress follows">ˈ</span><span title="'m' in 'my'">m</span><span title="/aɪ/ long 'i' in 'tide'">aɪ</span><span title="'k' in 'kind'">k</span><span title="'r' in 'rye'">r</span><span title="/ɵ/ variable 1st 'o' in 'omission'">ɵ</span><span title="'s' in 'sigh'">s</span><span title="/ɒː/ variable 'o' as in 'coffee'">ɒː</span><span title="'f' in 'find'">f</span><span title="'t' in 'tie'">t</span></span>/</a></span></span> (commonly referred to as <b>Microsoft</b>) is an American <a href="/wiki/Multinational_corporation" title="Multinational corporation">multinational</a> <a href="/wiki/Technology_company" title="Technology company">technology company</a> headquartered in <a href="/wiki/Redmond,_Washington" title="Redmond, Washington">Redmond</a>, <a href="/wiki/Washington_(state)" title="Washington (state)">Washington</a>, that develops, manufactures, licenses, supports and sells <a href="/wiki/Computer_software" title="Computer software" class="mw-redirect">computer software</a>, <a href="/wiki/Consumer_electronics" title="Consumer electronics">consumer electronics</a> and <a href="/wiki/Personal_computers" title="Personal computers" class="mw-redirect">personal computers</a> and services. Its best known software products are the <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Windows" title="Microsoft Windows">Microsoft Windows</a> line of <a href="/wiki/Operating_systems" title="Operating systems" class="mw-redirect">operating systems</a>, <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Office" title="Microsoft Office">Microsoft Office</a> <a href="/wiki/Office_suite" title="Office suite" class="mw-redirect">office suite</a>, and <a href="/wiki/Internet_Explorer" title="Internet Explorer">Internet Explorer</a> and <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Edge" title="Microsoft Edge">Edge</a> <a href="/wiki/Web_browser" title="Web browser">web browsers</a>. Its flagship hardware products are the <a href="/wiki/Xbox" title="Xbox">Xbox</a> game consoles and the <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Surface" title="Microsoft Surface">Microsoft Surface</a> tablet lineup. It is the <a href="/wiki/List_of_the_largest_software_companies" title="List of the largest software companies">world's largest software maker</a> measured by revenues. It is also one of the <a href="/wiki/List_of_corporations_by_market_capitalization" title="List of corporations by market capitalization" class="mw-redirect">world's most valuable companies</a>.</p>
<p>Microsoft was founded by <a href="/wiki/Paul_Allen" title="Paul Allen">Paul Allen</a> and <a href="/wiki/Bill_Gates" title="Bill Gates">Bill Gates</a> on April 4, 1975, to develop and sell <a href="/wiki/BASIC" title="BASIC">BASIC</a> <a href="/wiki/Interpreter_(computer_software)" title="Interpreter (computer software)" class="mw-redirect">interpreters</a> for <a href="/wiki/Altair_8800" title="Altair 8800">Altair 8800</a>. It rose to dominate the <a href="/wiki/Personal_computer" title="Personal computer">personal computer</a> <a href="/wiki/Operating_system" title="Operating system">operating system</a> market with <a href="/wiki/MS-DOS" title="MS-DOS">MS-DOS</a> in the mid-1980s, followed by <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Windows" title="Microsoft Windows">Microsoft Windows</a>. The company's 1986 <a href="/wiki/Initial_public_offering" title="Initial public offering">initial public offering</a>, and subsequent rise in its share price, created three billionaires and an estimated 12,000 millionaires from Microsoft employees. Since the 1990s, it has increasingly diversified from the operating system market and has <a href="/wiki/List_of_mergers_and_acquisitions_by_Microsoft" title="List of mergers and acquisitions by Microsoft">made a number of corporate acquisitions</a>. In May 2011, Microsoft acquired <a href="/wiki/Skype_Technologies" title="Skype Technologies">Skype Technologies</a> for $8.5 billion in its largest acquisition to date.</p>
<p>As of 2015, Microsoft is market dominant in both the <a href="/wiki/IBM_PC-compatible" title="IBM PC-compatible" class="mw-redirect">IBM PC-compatible</a> operating system (while it lost the majority of the overall operating system market to <a href="/wiki/Android_(operating_system)" title="Android (operating system)">Android</a>) and <a href="/wiki/Office_software_suite" title="Office software suite" class="mw-redirect">office software suite</a> markets (the latter with <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Office" title="Microsoft Office">Microsoft Office</a>). The company also produces a wide range of other software for desktops and servers, and is active in areas including <a href="/wiki/Web_search_engine" title="Web search engine">Internet search</a> (with <a href="/wiki/Bing" title="Bing">Bing</a>), the <a href="/wiki/Video_game_industry" title="Video game industry">video game industry</a> (with the <a href="/wiki/Xbox_(console)" title="Xbox (console)">Xbox</a>, <a href="/wiki/Xbox_360" title="Xbox 360">Xbox 360</a> and <a href="/wiki/Xbox_One" title="Xbox One">Xbox One</a> consoles), the digital services market (through <a href="/wiki/MSN" title="MSN">MSN</a>), and mobile phones (via the operating systems of Nokia's former phones and <a href="/wiki/Windows_Phone" title="Windows Phone">Windows Phone</a> OS). In June 2012, Microsoft entered the personal computer production market for the first time, with the launch of the <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Surface" title="Microsoft Surface">Microsoft Surface</a>, a line of <a href="/wiki/Tablet_computer" title="Tablet computer">tablet computers</a>.</p>
<p>With the acquisition of Nokia's devices and services division to form <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Mobile" title="Microsoft Mobile">Microsoft Mobile Oy</a>, the company re-entered the smartphone hardware market, after its previous attempt, <a href="/wiki/Microsoft_Kin" title="Microsoft Kin">Microsoft Kin</a>, which resulted from their acquisition of <a href="/wiki/Danger_(company)" title="Danger (company)">Danger Inc.</a></p>
<p>Microsoft is a portmanteau of the words <b>micro</b>computer and <b>soft</b>ware.</p>
```

Comment: Sorry, what changes giving a class? Is it faster than giving a property? Thanks for the answer

Comment: You are not affecting the element in motion. Faster, yes, the browser doesn't need to calculate the fixed position every time.

Comment: Ok, it's maybe faster, but I'm not sure this is an issue, I'll try and let you know.

Comment: @nikoloza this version has two severe speed advantages. 1) no calculation of the bounding rectangle 2) no tampering with the style attribute. Your version lags so badly, because these are both really expensive calculations.

Comment: Praveen, @Christoph thanks for your support guys. Please see my own answer to see the solution.